# C#: Adding Null-Item of the same type of other Items to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the problem that there are binding errors in my custom combobox (it derivates from the ComboBox from Windows Controls). There is a property called `AddNullItem` which adds a `ComboBoxItem` with the Content `Empty`.

`compositeCollection.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "Empty" });`

The Problem is that if you bind to this `ComboBox` and the Null-Item is selected, a binding error occurs, because the ComboBoxItems are not of the same type.

How can I add a ComboBoxItem of the same type of all other items or is there a better solution?

My solution was following:
`compositeCollection.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(this.Items.GetType()));`, but then occurs a XamlParseException.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the solution:

I created the instance of the IEnumerable Items, not the single item.
I used following:

```
object obj = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(t);
```